# Connect and open file share from Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-10, terminal

How can I connect to a file share address from Terminal and open it as folder in file explorer? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `start explorer \\server\share`

Comment: @WasifHasan Perfect. Thanks for this. Please feel free to add this as answer so I can mark it as solution.

Comment: Thanks posted an answer please upvote and mark as accepted and also check out the other answer in your other question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
start explorer \\server\share
```

Answer (score 1):

net use Z: \remotepc\share /u:domainname\username password

this will create networked drive.